# Django ImageField not render at <img> tag HTML

Tags: html, django, jinja2, href, imagefield

> ```
>  # models.py
> ```

```
from django.db import models
from . import constants

class Photos(models.Model):
    band_member = models.ForeignKey(BandMember,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    photo_description = models.TextField(max_length=400)

class Photos(models.Model):
    band_member = models.ForeignKey(BandMember,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    photo_description = models.TextField(max_length=400)

    @property
    def photo_url(self):
        if self.photo and hasattr(self.photo, 'url'):
            return self.photo.url
```

> ```
> #  views.py
> ```

```
def member_photos(request,member_id):
    current_member = BandMember.objects.get(pk=member_id)
    photos = current_member.photos_set.all()
    context = {
        'all_photos': photos,
        'current_member': current_member,
              }
    return render(request,'band_members/member_photos.html', context)
```

> html file :

```
{% if all_photos %}
   {% for foto in all_photos %}
        <img class"" src="{{ foto.photo_url }}"  
        alt = {{foto.photo_url }}">
        <h5>{{ foto.photo_description }}</h5>
   {% endfor %}
```

Although , image is not displayed , alt displays the correct path of the file

What am i doing wrong ? 
What i'm trying to achieve , is when user clicks on a 'SHOW PHOTOS' button at a page containing informations about a specific band member

(site/band_member/member_id here ), another page loads (site/band_member/member_id/photos) , displaying all the photos of the current member.

NEW TO DJANGO !!! 
Thank you !
sorry for my 'bad english' language :)

Comment: In that last snippet of the HTML file you are missing an equals sign after "class" and a double-quote after the equals sign in "alt =". I am no suggesting this is the problem, but you may want to check your html file. Anyway, after checking that file, load the page in your browser and view the source of the page. What appears where the img src should be? Anything? An error message?

Comment: Could you post the path you are saying that is showing?

Comment: You are missing a "=" in `class""`

Comment: The path that it displays is "media/picture 1. jpg".  when I print photos variable at the console,  it return a Query set List..

Answer (score 1):

The html inside the loop is not correct. Try fixing that like this.

```
 <img src="{{ foto.photo_url }}" alt ="{{foto.photo_url }}">
 <h5>{{ foto.photo_description }}</h5>
```